# Features of twilo free account

Tags: twilio

I am working on small college project where i need to send sms on successful registration of a user. Can I use twilo free account to do the same?
Or I need to have the paid account only?

Comment: Some one please answer? why downvoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send SMS with the free trial on Twilio, but it is a [limited number](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-does-twilios-free-trial-work). You must also be able to provide an existing number to verify your account.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the link.